# How do I unlock all of my rig bones at once?

Tags: rigging, bones, transforms, rigify, pose-mode

Every time I generate a rig, the Transform tools for the bones are locked. I can unlock the bones one by one, but that seems inefficient. Is there a way to unlock them all at once?

[image]

[image]

Here is a link to the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z1J-aT5Ai7X55wz9LKvCzDQi_TWiFTaI/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Select them all and use the Alt key while unlocking one of them. (if you're using "emulate 3 button mouse" in the preferences, uncheck this option first as it uses the alt key).

Comment: I hope you know what you're doing, because in this Rigify rig the locked bones are supposed to stay in their place, or the rig will break.

Comment: @joshsanfelici I am new to rigging so all of this is new to me. How do I make it so I can pose the bones without breaking the rig?

Comment: In the "N" propeties panel of the 3D window you have to activate the layers which contain the control bones, those which have a wire control shape (Face, Torso, Arm, Leg, Root). You should also turn off the others bone layers, knowing that the bones which will actually deform the mesh are in layer number 30 (and they also are supposed not to be touched directly).

Comment: @joshsanfelici Thank you! this fixed the problem!